# How to convert a temperature readout to a K-type thermocouple voltage? (reverse thermocouple converter)

Tags: temperature, thermocouple

I am working with a commercial heating controller device which takes in a thermocouple input in order to regulate the heating temperature. However, in some cases, the thermocouple junction just isn't suitable to accurately measure the temperature being generated by the heating element -- the only method to reliably measure the temperature in that case is an infrared camera.

Now, the infrared camera gives out readings through serial communication to a computer... and I have no way to give this input to the commercial controller which takes ONLY thermocouple input. Due to this, I am forced to manually read the temperature from the Infrared camera and control the output by hand which wastes a lot of my time and ends up with terrible temperature control.

So, is there an easy way to rig up/buy something which can easily convert a temperature readout to a thermocouple output? This is an exact reverse of the traditional thermocouple readout ICs which are available in plenty in the market.

Comment: Some kind of DAC will happily "convert" a digital input to analog output.

Comment: Harsha, at least make sure you understand some of the physics behind thermocouples and also what cold-junction compensation is. See: [Omega's short discussion here](https://www.omega.com/en-us/resources/thermocouple-junction-principles).

Comment: What is your temperature range and accuracy needed?

Comment: That is inasane. You can get an industrial controller with voltage input 0..10V or current loop input 4..20mA, it's an industrial standard. Then you have pyrometer sensors that output the same 0...10V or 4..20mA,